# Why isn't this portion of HTML rendering and why do I get a undefined method `cardsets' for nil:NilClass in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to add a flashcards(cardsets) feature in Rails and I'm having some problems implementing this as I'm getting an `undefined method`cardsets' for nil:NilClass` error

I can get the page to render if I change: `<% if @user.cardsets.any? %>` to `<% unless @cardsets.any? %>` but the corresponding cardsets are being shown when I do this.
Here is the html.erb code that is producing this error:

```
<% provide(:title, "Flashcards") %>
<h1>Flashcards</h1>

<div class="row">
  <aside class="span3">
    <%= render "shared/cardset_form" %>
  </aside>
  <div class="span6">
    **<% if @user.cardsets.any? %>**
        <h3>Flashcard Sets (<%= @user.cardsets.count %>)</h3>
        <ol class="cardsets">
          <% @user.cardsets.each do |cardset| %>
              <li>
                <span class="topic"><%= link_to cardset.topic, show_cardset_path(cardset) %></span>
                <%= link_to "edit", edit_cardset_path(cardset) %>
                <%= render partial: "shared/delete_link", locals: {item: cardset} %>
              </li>
          <% end %>
        </ol>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've starred the line that is producing the `undefined method`cardsets' for nil:NilClass` error.

This is what's in my cardsets_controller.rb:

```
class CardsetsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :signed_in_user, only: [:new, :index, :create, :edit, :destroy, :update]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @cardsets = Cardset.all
  end

  def show
    @cardset = Cardset.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @cardset = current_user.cardsets.build(cardset_params)
    if @cardset.save
      flash[:success] = "A new set of flashcards have been created!"
      redirect_to @cardset
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def new
    @cardset = Cardset.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    @cardset = Cardset.find(params[:id])
    if @cardset.update_attributes(cardset_params)
      flash[:success] = "You've updated your flashcards!"
      redirect_to @cardset
    else
      render "edit"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @cardset = Cardset.find(params[:id])
    @cardset.delete
    redirect_to cardsets_path
  end

  private

    def cardset_params
      params.require(:cardset).permit(:topic, :description)
    end

    def correct_user
      @cardset = current_user.cardsets.find_by_id(params[:id])
      redirect_to root_url if @cardset.nil?
    end
end
```

Here is the code in my cardset.rb file:

```
class Cardset < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :topic, presence: true
end
```

Here is the code in my user.rb file:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cardsets
  (...a bunch of other code...) 
end
```

If anyone could provide some help or suggestions on where I may be going wrong I'd greatly appreciate it!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you aren't setting `@user` in your Controller, so `@user` is `nil`.

You probably want to either define `@user` or maybe you meant to use `@cardsets`.

Comment: You didn't exactly give me the answer but you led me to it after tinkering more with my code.  I ended up removing the "@user" variable from the html.erb file and everything now works.  I guess Rails already assumed I was referring to the user from the model association, so deleting it was necessary.  Thanks a lot!